# Database backed Session does not save when response()->json() is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, oracle

I am getting exception while saving my JsonResult to database (oracle of type clob)

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["myObject"] = filterContext.Result;
```

Error:

Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Comment: Custom session state:
https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1422/custom-session-state-in-asp-dot-net

Comment: Can you provide stack trace for more information? This issue usually occurs when certain class stored in session state is not marked as `[Serializable()]` attribute. If it's a partial class, you can create another partial definition in separate file and mark it with `[Serializable()]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I create a new class, I populate my result and used Serializable as attribute. worked for me

```
[Serializable]
public class myclass
{
}
```